# SQLite getting latest specific entries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a data flow from a lot of sensors and I am capturing their status (Clear/Locked etc) and "Group" and other info and saving the DateTime with each Row. 
Group can be

```
"floor"
"yard"
"bath"
```

etc

There is only ever two full days of data so the database itself is not all that big. On demand, I need to select the last entry for selected Group or Groups. As in...

Show the Last entries for "floor" and "bath" (which should be their current state)...

```
floor Clear 2016-09-22 12:43:37
bath Locked 2016-09-21 09:10:14
```

I have searched and can't find exactly what I need as I think mostly because the search keywords are too general. Would someone be kind enough to get me going in the right direction.

Comment: I've removed the Delphi, Lazarus and Zeos tags, as your question has absolutely nothing to do with any of those topics. This is a straight-up SQL question related to SQLite3, and I've tagged it as such.

Comment: I agree - this is a very poor description of the problem. I was thinking of the 'SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM table GROUP BY "Group"' as well, but the OP seems to use sqlite3 where this does not work for timestamp fields. Or maybe the issue is that the field "Group" must be quoted in the SQL instruction?

Comment: Most likely it has to be escaped. It's a horrific idea to use a reserved word as a column name in any DBMS; it just makes everything you do with that column a struggle. Much better to use another name and then alias it if needed for display (`SELECT aBetterColumnName AS "Group" FROM...`).